# Wpf: using separate dbcontext in application lifetime

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, thread-safety, dbcontext

I have a wpf application with dependency injection. I registered my context as service to use in app like below.

```
serviceCollection.AddDbContext<Context>(p => p.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

I have another service that should fetch data from database every 15 seconds to check for new entities added and i do it with an event service and start the service in *MainWindow.xaml* startup and it goes to another thread.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task newOrdersTask = _eventService.SubscribeToNewOrders();
}
```

But sometimes while working with appplication i get this error.

**A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed**

How can i handle these scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to have a singleton DbContext in your entire application, especially when working on different threads is being considered.

Passing `ServiceLifetime.Transient` as the second argument to `AddDbContext` will force 
 creation of a new DbContext every time it gets injected by the container. 
However, by doing so, you are going to miss a lot of features EF Core DbContext provides by default. You may consider implementing something like "[ambient context pattern](https://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/)" to somehow preserve these features.